# Draggable Columns in ASP.NET GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Is there any open source that extends ASP.NET GridView, which allows Column order to be changed after it's rendered, raises a server side event when a Column is Dragged & Dopped ? I should be able to do this myself. I am wondering If there's any already.

Also, am just curious How long would it take for you to get this feature implemented.Just to know where I stand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GridView in .NET 3.0+ supports this feature, are you tied to an earlier release?

Comment: I'd search on a well known search engine for "free asp.net grid", you'd be amazed at what's out there.

Comment: Thanks, I chose approach mentioned in [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164033.aspx] and got it to work.

Comment: @Lazarus - Can u let me know how to do it with .NET 3.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

[Component Art's grid](http://www.componentart.com/webui/grid.aspx) has this functionality, but it s not open source

Answer (score 0):

try jquery based flexigrid